# Read server response in bootstrap file input plugin in ASP.NET MVC site

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have an ASP.NET MVC app. This app uses the [bootstrap file input](http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input) plugin. After a file is uploaded, I need to examine the JSON that is returned. At this time, my code is structured like the following:

**Index.cshtml**

```
<input id="myPictures" name="files" type="file" multiple>

...

$('#myPictures').on('filebatchuploadcomplete', function(event, files, extra)   
{
  console.log(event);
  console.log(files);
  console.log(extra);
});

$("#myPictures").fileinput({
  maxFileCount: 1,
  overwriteInitial: false,
  uploadUrl: "/Pictures/Upload",
  uploadAsync: true,
  previewSettings: {
    image: {width: "200px", height: "200px"}
  }
});
```

**PicturesController.cs**

```
public class PicturesController
{
  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult Upload(FormCollection form)
  {
    // Do stuff
    var resultId = GetResultId();
    return Json(new { id = pictureId }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }
}
```

My problem is, while the JSON is being returned, I cannot seem to access it in the `filebatchuploadcomplete` event handler. I have confirmed that the `Upload` action is returning the JSON I expect by using breakpoints and Fiddler. However, I cannot figure out how to read the response to react based on the server's result.

Can somebody please help me figure out how to read the value of the `id` property in the JSON object that is returned from the server? It's driving me nuts!

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this using the event you are using as it does pot provide the response. Try the [success event instead](http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input#event-filebatchuploadsuccess).

```
$('#myPictures').on('filebatchuploadsuccess', function(event, data, previewId, index) { 
  console.log(data.response);   // id is in data.response
});
```

If you were using filebatchuploadcomplete instead of success so you could handle errors, you may have to handle those separately using the [specific error events](http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input#error-events).